Flutter crash on Stream.first - how to debug
Firebase Crashlytics reported this crash in our Flutter app, but there's no pointer to anywhere in our own codebase; it's all coming from stream.dart and related implementation. Any tips on how to troubleshoot?
Fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError: Bad state: No element      
#00 pc 0x5c4d0b com.mycom (Stream.first.<anonymous closure> [stream.dart:1583])      
#01 pc 0x598fd3 com.mycom (_RootZone.runGuarded [zone.dart:1582]) 
#02 pc 0x4db917 com.mycom (_BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone [stream_impl.dart:418]) 
#03 pc 0x4db74f com.mycom (_BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone [stream_impl.dart:428]) 
#04 pc 0x49eae7 com.mycom (_BufferingStreamSubscription._close [stream_impl.dart:317]) 
#05 pc 0x39231b com.mycom (_ForwardingStream._handleDone [stream_pipe.dart:99]) 
#06 pc 0x3922bb com.mycom (_ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleDone [stream_pipe.dart:161]) 
#07 pc 0x392283 com.mycom (_ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleDone [stream_pipe.dart:160]) 
#08 pc 0x598fd3 com.mycom (_RootZone.runGuarded [zone.dart:1582]) 
#09 pc 0x4db917 com.mycom (_BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone [stream_impl.dart:418]) 
#10 pc 0x4db74f com.mycom (_BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone [stream_impl.dart:428]) 
#11 pc 0x51484b com.mycom (_DelayedDone.perform [stream_impl.dart:560]) 
#12 pc 0x49bcb7 com.mycom (_PendingEvents.handleNext [stream_impl.dart:646]) 
#13 pc 0x49bc03 com.mycom (_PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> [stream_impl.dart:617]) 
#14 pc 0x1f8ca7 com.mycom (_microtaskLoop [schedule_microtask.dart:40]) 
#15 pc 0x598df7 com.mycom (_startMicrotaskLoop [schedule_microtask.dart:49]) 
#16 pc 0x1f8c17 com.mycom (_startMicrotaskLoop [schedule_microtask.dart:44]) 

Search on Stackoverflow and some research but not found a good pointer.
